# How to suggest that a closed question be migrated to another site?

Tags: support

I was surprised to see this question was closed but probably the reason is my background. I think it would be a very nice question at Mathematics Stack Exchange. Is there some way I could suggest that it be migrated?

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88380/abbreviation-or-expression-for-we-will-prove-that

Comment: Sure there is - you just did! Unfortunately there's nothing non-mod community members can do to migrate the question. A EL&U mod will have to do it. That might be expedited if you can get high-rep or mod Math.SE users to comment on the question (or here on this Meta question) that they'd welcome it on their stack. Sometimes unilaterally migrating a question from Stack A to Stack B can seem like A is foisting it on B.

Answer (score 2):

The question you link is too old to be migrated, even from moderators. Otherwise, you could flag it for moderation attention, and explain what you want to suggest about the migration. Consider that moderators could not migrate it, though; first, they generally ask to the moderators of the other site, and if they don't want it, it doesn't get migrated.